What are these lighting bolts near some Graces?
In Elden Ring, on the map, there are some weird things that look vaguely like lightning bolts. You can see multiple in these images here:


They appear to point at some Sites of Grace, but not all of them.
What do they signify?

Those are directions to the next most relevant site of grace, ending up at major bosses.
That is, to get to the nearest major boss, follow the rays from the grace to find the next grace or the boss itself.

@I0b0 what defines the “next most relevant site of grace”? And to clarify, do they point to the sites they’re right next to, with the end where the two “prongs” are?

@Daemons They form a trail. The rays extend from the site of grace and point towards the next one, or a boss.
